# Error installing MiKTeX 2.9 on Windows

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

The basic MiKTeX 2.9 installation fails on Windows. So I edit the log file after a cleaning cession to eliminate dust from the first failing trial.

Here is a simplest log file after cleaning a lot of things (mainly due to the first fail to install MiKTeX):

```
2016-12-03 17:37:28,244+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-03 17:37:28,307+0100 INFO  initexmf - Registering root directories...
2016-12-03 17:37:28,540+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-03 17:37:28,610+0100 INFO  initexmf - Removing fndb (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2016-12-03 17:37:29,956+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-03 17:37:30,032+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Jean-Claude\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2016-12-03 17:37:30,033+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory (C:\Users\Jean-Claude\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2016-12-03 17:37:30,033+0100 INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Tex")...
2016-12-03 17:37:30,037+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2016-12-03 17:37:30,112+0100 INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\outils\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2016-12-03 17:37:38,698+0100 INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
2016-12-03 17:37:38,939+0100 FATAL initexmf - A MiKTeX configuration file could not be loaded.
2016-12-03 17:37:38,939+0100 FATAL initexmf - Info: file="C:\Program Files (x86)\Tex\miktex/config\scripts.ini", line="147", error="the file has been tampered with"
2016-12-03 17:37:38,940+0100 FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Cfg\Cfg.cpp
2016-12-03 17:37:38,940+0100 FATAL initexmf - Line: 1138
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you have a previous installationt that you uninstalled? It seems two MiKTeX processes are running simultaneously.

Comment: Here is a simplest log file after cleaning a lot of things

Comment: The error message from the installer is
The executed process could not proceed
Details: fileName="c:\outils\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", arguments="--rmfndb --admin -- log-file="C:\outils\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/config\uninst.log" --verbose", exitCode="1"

Comment: executing initexmf.exe with administrator privilege, we have a message window with the message: This application can't be executed on your PC (translated from a french message). So, initexmf seems necessary to a successful installation, but doesn't work on windows 10 (on my machine)

Answer (score 4):

Solved after a lot of steps and trial. So, my answer is just a list of ideas:

- after each failing trial, remove all installed files
- unactive your antivirus on the install directory
- execute the installer as administrator
- check if there is another tool which as something to do with latex and remove it from the path
- avoid blank in the install path

and then, with some luck, you will install MiKTeX.

Comment: Try with the solution of Jean-Claude Moissinac. For my opinion is the best.